# Conditionally return values from LEFT JOIN between 3 tables based on CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, left-join, case

First off, apologies for a long post. It's really more simple than it looks ;-)

I'm trying to do something that I think is conceptually simple, and I believe I'm most of the way there, but there's one last part that I can't implement without errors that I can't figure out how to fix.

I have three related tables.

**Orders**:
Each row is an Order with a unique ID, there will never be duplicates.

```
+---------+---------+
| OrderID | Name    |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | Order 1 |
| 2       | Order 2 |
| 3       | Order 3 |
+---------+---------+
```

**Order Details:**
Relational table where each row is a product line on an order.

```
+---------+-----------+
| OrderID | ProductID |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | a         |
| 2       | b         |
| 2       | c         |
| 3       | a         |
| 3       | b         |
| 3       | b         |
+---------+-----------+
```

As you can see some orders have just one product (1), some will have multiple products (2) and some will have duplicate products (3).

**Products**
Each row is a product with a unique ID, there will never be duplicates.

```
+-----------+-------------+
| ProductID | Description |
+-----------+-------------+
| a         | Chicken     |
| b         | Fish        |
| c         | Beef        |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to return all rows from the Orders table and conditionally return some information about the related Products in one column.

The condition is that I look at how many `DISTINCT` products each Order has. If it's just 1 then I want to return the Product Description value. If it's more than 1 then I want to return some placeholder text such as 'Multi'.

I think that I need to use `CASE` to get this working, but I can't figure it out.

I can count the unique products successfully like this:

```
SELECT 
    o.Name
   ,COUNT(DISTINCT d.ProductId) as 'Unique Products'
FROM Orders o

LEFT JOIN OrderDetails d ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
LEFT JOIN Products p on d.ProductId = p.ProductId

GROUP BY o.Name
ORDER BY o.Name DESC

GO
```

Results are like this:

```
+---------+-----------------+
| Name    | Unique Products |
+---------+-----------------+
| Order 1 | 1               |
| Order 2 | 2               |
| Order 3 | 2               |
+---------+-----------------+
```

What I want is this:

```
+---------+-----------------+
| Name    | Unique Products |
+---------+-----------------+
| Order 1 | Chicken         |
| Order 2 | Multi           |
| Order 3 | Multi           |
+---------+-----------------+
```

I have been trying to use `CASE` which I believe I've gotten correct:

```
CASE WHEN (COUNT(DISTINCT d.ProductId)) > 1 THEN 'Multi' ELSE p.Description END AS 'Products'
```

However unless I add p.Description to `GROUP BY` then I get the error (which I understand):

> Column 'Product.Description' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But if I do add it the results aren't what I want, for example:

```
+---------+----------+
| Name    | Products |
+---------+----------+
| Order 1 | Chicken  |
| Order 2 | Fish     |
| Order 2 | Beef     |
| Order 3 | Chicken  |
| Order 3 | Fish     |
| Order 3 | Fish     |
+---------+----------+
```

When it should just say "Order 2 - Multi" on one row for example. **This is the bit I don't understand**.

If can get some help on this bit alone it would solve my problem and I'd accept the answer. However...

**Bonus Round**

The above is fine and all, but if this bit is possible I'd accept this as an answer above the others.

Can I concatenate the product names? I've been looking at `COALESCE` and `FOR XML PATH` but I can't wrap my head around them at all so I don't even have any code to show.

Results would look something like this:

```
+---------+--------------+
| Name    | Products     |
+---------+--------------+
| Order 1 | Chicken      |
| Order 2 | Fish;Beef    |
| Order 3 | Chicken;Fish |
+---------+--------------+
```

If you've made it this far I commend you! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are pretty close.  You just need some `case` logic and an aggregation function around the description:

```
SELECT o.Name,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT d.ProductId)  = 1
             THEN MAX(p.description)
             ELSE 'Multi'
        END) as Descriptions
FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN
     OrderDetails d
     ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID LEFT JOIN
     Products p
     ON d.ProductId = p.ProductId
GROUP BY o.Name
ORDER BY o.Name DESC
```

The second part is a very different question.  In SQL Server, you need to use an XML subquery:

```
select o.Name,
       stuff((select distinct ',' + p.description
              from OrderDetails d left join
                   Products p
                   on d.ProductId = p.ProductId
              where o.OrderID = d.OrderID 
              for xml path (''), type
             ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'
                    ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as descriptions
from Orders o
order by o.Name desc
```

Comment: Great speed :) Change `,` with `;` and remove `DESC` from `ORDER BY`. **[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6fd0e6/12/0)**

Comment: Gordon, you're like some kind of cybernetic wizard from the future. That was amazingly fast and both work absolutely great. If I could upvote more than once I would. Thanks very much indeed!

Comment: Be careful when using  `FOR XML` when working with user input. If `p.description` contains invalid XML characters this will throw an error. [More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500235.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Edwin, I'll definitely bear this in mind. Thankfully I think they're all alphanumeric so we're safe...for now ;-)

Comment: @EdwinStoteler . . . Sigh.  Why doesn't SQL Server just add a proper string aggregation function.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Not sure, but Microsoft probably doesn't want to encourage string manipulation in this way in SQL. Since these kind of manipulations are often done in application layer, and those languages are often better suited for it. But I have to admit I had to use it many times.